# Why Concurrent Collector in Java besides using ConcurrentMap does not use some Concurrent List Implementation?

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda, collections, java-stream

Consider the signature of the `concurrentGroupBy`:

`static <T,K> Collector<T,?,ConcurrentMap<K,List<T>>>   groupingByConcurrent(Function<? super T,? extends K> classifier)`

Here consider the diagram below on how the parallel threads might be filling in the data into the respective lists corresponding to the respective keys.

[image]

- Now - since at given point in time - there can be **multiple threads that might be filling in a given list** - why **doesn't the implementation internally use some concurrent implementation of List?**
- the API documentation states that it does not provide any guarantees for the implementation to the thread safe - but shouldn't the **list implementation be thread safe for this overall implementation to be actually concurrent?**

Comment: What is `concurrentGroupBy` in your opening sentence? Did you mean to write `groupingByConcurrent`?

Answer (score 2):

*Short answer*:

There are two types of concurrent list implementations: synchronized versions of regular lists and `java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList`. On the one hand synchronized lists are not different from regular lists, on the other hand `CopyOnWriteArrayList` was designed for cases when reads are much more frequent than writes (it's totally not the case for a collector).

*Long answer*:

If we have a look at how `groupingByConcurrent(Function<? super T,? extends K> classifier)` works under the hood we will see that it just calls:

```java
return groupingByConcurrent(classifier, ConcurrentHashMap::new, toList());
```

So by default it uses the regular `toList()` collector which is not concurrent (It doesn't contain `Collector.Characteristics.CONCURRENT` in its characteristics).

If you call the method above directly you will be able to supply it with a concurrent collector if you want. For example you could implement a collector that adds to `java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList` if you find it somehow beneficial but it would recreate an underlying array every time you insert into it. Most likely it won't create a performance boost. All the other concurrent implementations are more or less messing around just wrapping the call with additional synchronization (like `Collections.synchronizedList()`).

And it's basically what happens inside of the `Collector<T, ?, M> groupingByConcurrent(Function<? super T, ? extends K> classifier, Supplier<M> mapFactory, Collector<? super T, A, D> downstream)` method.
Here is the code snippet from JDK:

```java
    if (downstream.characteristics().contains(Collector.Characteristics.CONCURRENT)) {
            accumulator = (m, t) -> {
                K key = Objects.requireNonNull(classifier.apply(t), "element cannot be mapped to a null key");
                A resultContainer = m.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> downstreamSupplier.get());
                downstreamAccumulator.accept(resultContainer, t);
            };
        }
        else {
            accumulator = (m, t) -> {
                K key = Objects.requireNonNull(classifier.apply(t), "element cannot be mapped to a null key");
                A resultContainer = m.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> downstreamSupplier.get());
                synchronized (resultContainer) {
                    downstreamAccumulator.accept(resultContainer, t);
                }
            };
        }
```

It checks internally whether a nested collector is concurrent and if it's not, just surrounds the mutating call with a `synchronized` block.

It means that there's no need to do a double synchronization in this case as built-in concurrent list implementations in JDK are mostly just synchronized versions of regular lists.